# Can I used business/shop photos on my personal blog

Tags: copyright, photo

My personal blog is about family friendly events in my community. Can I use pictures on a business' website for my blog?
For example, if I write a post about museums in my city,  I go to the museums' website and grab pictures from there?
I'm not benefitting directly from these pictures. Just want to create a sense of awareness in my community.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What country are you and the museum in?

Answer (score 2):

As @DominiqueH points out, even when you are not commercially benefitting from the images, there are copyright issues to consider when using images from other websites.

If you really feel you need to use images on their website, I would advise contacting the website owner first and ask if you can use them.  Be specific on what images you wish to use and how.  Are you going to alter their size?  Are you cropping any?

Other than that, using Google Images can help but I would be careful doing that.  Even though they may show up as copyright free, they may not necessarily be so.  I would use a royalty free stock photos site such as Pixabay, Pexels or Unsplash.  That way if any problems do arise with anyone claiming copyright you have a specific source to refer to in order to claim reasonable belief that they were royalty and copyright free.

Answer (score 1):

Usually not. Each picture has copyrights and usages that are decided by the author. But you can find online many images that are legally free of right that you can reuse. On Google Image Search you can use the Usage Right filter and see only the image you have the right to copy.